# QGIS installation vanished! Re-installation attempts produce dependency-errors

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu

So, I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and use Qgis 3.4 for GIS analysis. I had a week long pause using QGIS for about a week, and it was quite an unhappy surprise to find out this morning that the whole program had vanished from my OS! I cannot figure out anything else I could have done, but used the software update once as prompted so by the system and installing some new R-packages.

So, I tried re-installation of QGIS, and here come my old friends: dependency issues. Can anyone figure out what is going on here?

```
> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass saga
Hit:1 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 https://qgis.org/debian bionic InRelease                                 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/albertomilone/hamster-indicator/ubuntu 
bionic InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu 
bionic InRelease
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease 
[83,2 kB]    
Fetched 83,2 kB in 1s (89,2 kB/s)                                
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
saga is already the newest version (2.3.1+dfsg-4~bionic0).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python-qgis : Depends: libqgis-analysis3.4.2 but it is not going to be 
installed
qgis : Depends: gdal-abi-2-2-3
       Depends: libqgis-analysis3.4.2 but it is not going to be 
       installed
       Depends: libqgis-app3.4.2 but it is not going to be installed
qgis-plugin-grass : Depends: libqgis-app3.4.2 but it is not going to 
be installed
Depends: grass740
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried installing the missing packages, with no luck:

```
> sudo apt-get install gdal-abi-2-2-3 libqgis-analysis3.4.2 libqgis- 
app3.4.2 grass740
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gdal-abi-2-2-3 is a virtual package provided by:
libgdal20 2.2.3+dfsg-2 [Not candidate version]

Package grass740 is a virtual package provided by:
grass-core 7.4.0-1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'gdal-abi-2-2-3' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'grass740' has no installation candidate
```

**Update**:

According to the advice by Heikki I switched the Debian repository to Ubuntugis. Then I removed my previous installation using:

```
sudo apt-get remove qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass saga
```

Then I tried re-installation, but still get the same error. There is still the problem of libgis-analysis3.4.2, gdal-abi-2-2-3 and libgis-app3.4.2 being unmet dependencies that cannot be installed for some reason.

Comment: Since you are using UbuntuGIS, you should also be using the corresponding QGIS repo. "https://qgis.org/ubuntugis bionic main" Instead of the Debian repo you have.

Comment: I tried this but it did not fix the problem. Updated the attempt to the question.

Comment: And if you try without GRASS and SAGA? sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis

Comment: It still gives the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntugis way is currently broken, because update cycles of Ubuntugis and QGIS are not in sync.

You have to wait for the next point release, or switch to the qgis ubuntu repo and remove all ubuntugis packages.

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. The whole reason for this mess was that I was using the debian packages... Strange though, that they worked for me before. All works fine now. Thank you!

Comment: The qgis debian repo alone would have worked, but not together with the ubuntugis ppa. In fact, qgis debian and ubuntu repos share the same content, only qgis ubuntugis is different.

Comment: @AndreJ Are you aware of any proposed plans to fix these unsynced dependencies? thanks

Comment: No, there are no plans, because both projects (QGIS and ubuntugis) don't have enough manpower to do so. Feel free to volunteer ... The nightly packages are fixed earlier, but might have other issues. Or disable the ubuntugis ppa once you have installed a proper working QGIS version until the next QGIS point release.

Comment: How do I remove the ubuntugis packages?  I tried `sudo apt-get remove ubuntugis` but it found nothing.  How do I find the packages to remove?

Comment: @jua-kali `ubuntugis` is not a package name. You have to put qgis, python-qgis etc in there.And run `apt-cache policy qgis` after disabling the ppa to see what is available for you.

Answer (score 6):

In this specific case, you should remove the `ubuntugis` repository.

Then downgrade gdal (from 2.3.2 that came from `ubuntugis`) to version 2.2.3.

`sudo apt install gdal-bin=2.2.3+dfsg-2 libgdal20=2.2.3+dfsg-2 libgdal-dev=2.2.3+dfsg-2 libgdal-java=2.2.3+dfsg-2 gdal-data=2.2.3+dfsg-2 python-gdal=2.2.3+dfsg-2 python3-gdal=2.2.3+dfsg-2`

The install qgis from `qgis.org/ubuntu` repo:

`sudo apt install libqgis-analysis3.4.2 libqgis-app3.4.2 python-qgis qgis qgis-plugin-grass`

If you want to install saga, well, you also have to fix a minor problem in the version names of the opencv packages.

Install saga with:

`sudo apt install libopencv-flann3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 libopencv-highgui3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 libopencv-ml3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 libopencv-core3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 libopencv-videoio3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1  libopencv-imgcodecs3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 libopencv-imgproc3.2=3.2.0+dfsg-4ubuntu0.1 saga-common saga python-saga libsaga libsaga-dev`

You should end up with QGIS 3.4.2, GRASS and SAGA.

[image]

Comment: Hi, it worked for me except for the grass plugin. I'm luky because I don't use it. I received an error said missing dependecies for grass740. Thank you very much

Comment: To have GRASS supported in QGIS, try `sudo apt install grass-core grass-doc libqgisgrass7-3.4.2 qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common qgis-provider-grass` and tell us which are the missing dependencies.

Comment: version numbers have changed here or there but the concept works : force-install the precise version they say "but it is not going to be installed". `sudo apt install python3-qgis=3.4.8+dfsg-1~bionic0` - that seems to be pulling everything in.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original poster's problem may have been because they included gdal-abi-x in their `sudo apt-get install` command.  Apparently gdal-abi is a virtual package; not sure what that means but apt may have crapped out when it couldn't find gdal-abi.  The original poster may have had more success if they left gdal-abi out and installed all the other missing dependencies, then tried installing qgis again.

```
    e.g. sudo apt-get install libqgis-analysis3.4.2 libqgis-app3.4.2 ... (my error message said I needed libqgis-core, libqgis-gui, and a bunch more)
         sudo apt-get install qgis
```

This whole thing just happened to me - I had QGIS 3.8 Zanzibar running just fine on my computer until it disappeared.  I am almost positive that it disappeared because I ran `sudo apt autoremove.` I was installing R and a number of associated packages (adding repositories and subsequently running `apt update` and `apt upgrade`), and apt prompted me to run autoremove to clear a list of packages that were **"installed and are no longer required"**.  The message listed a number of packages that I thought were familiar looking, but I figured it was safe... well, QGIS was no longer installed on my computer after I ran autoremove - so my current understanding is that autoremove is not "safe."

I found this thread and added the UbuntuGIS repository to my list (with the debian & ubuntu repositories), but that didn't work for me.

With some guidance from https://askubuntu.com/questions/995435/apt-autoremove-trying-to-remove-essential-packages/1171212#1171212, I was able to get QGIS back on my computer by leaving the terminal open after I ran `sudo apt-get install qgis` (which gave me a similar error message as the original poster) - so I could see which dependencies were keeping it from installing.  Then I opened synaptic package manager (installed through the software center), and installed all the dependencies I could find.  Gdal-abi was the only one I couldn't find - but it didn't appear to matter in the end - after installing the other dependencies, qgis installed through synaptic.  Gdal appears to run fine (I'm crossing my fingers) - the gdal slope algorithm worked successfully on a dem.

Somewhere in my [very] limited understanding of things, I wonder if installing libgdal1-dev made apt think that my current qgis and gdal installations were unnecessary (I installed libgdal1-dev while I was installing some spatial analysis packages for R - recommended by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syBPX0a4THA).

Thankfully my plugins and profiles were reincarnated - I don't understand enough about linux software installation but apt autoremove didn't touch ../.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me after I installed rasterio and followed blindly their installation steps.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-numpy gdal-bin libgdal-dev
$ pip install rasterio
```

That's a bad move, as QGIS disappeared.

To get it back, I deactivated the ubuntugis ppa, and uninstalled gdal-bin, libgdal-dev and gdal-data.

Then : `sudo apt-get autoremove`

And finally I could install QGIS back.

You have to uninstall all the packages that came with ubuntugis, but gdal-data was hard to find as I didn't install it manually. Luckily its name started with gdal.

And for the people who want use QGIS and have rasterio installed, follow rasterio's instructions without adding the ubuntugis ppa !